# Order lifecycle - Model in object or in separate class

Tags: java, model, lifecycle

```
@Entity
public class Order{

     @ManyToOne
     private LocalStore store;
     private OrderStatus status;


     public void acceptOrder(LocalStore store){
        //business logic
     }
}
```

Is is better to have lifecycle methods in the domain object? 
Would it better to have this in a different class? (for example..the above would probably force LocalStore to cascade persistence.)

Comment: Personally I try to implement logic like this in a Service or any other handler for that matter. I believe entities (or just objects) are to store data and for that I try to keep it as clean as possible. Sure, you might need to implement a method to convert some value, but to apply logic like accepting orders. That's not really the job of an entity, is it?

Comment: @Aquillo Is there some kind of design pattern for this?

Comment: Well, you could try to search on 'Object oriented design pattern' or something simular. I'm searching too at the moment, will let you know if something interesting turns up.

Comment: You can read up on [Domain Logic Patterns](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/), which mandate, as a best practice, a clear separation of your domain model and your service layer.

Comment: Any examples of a Service which manipulates the OrderStatus lifecycle...would be interested to see how people do this.